# Making Justify (Perfect) alignment in the PlotLegend

Tags: legending, alignment

I am trying to plot some datasets ({L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9, atmve, atmvebar, atmvmu, atmvmubar, DSNve, DSNvebar, DSNvx}) using ListLogLogPlot. For that I have written this following code-:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, 
  L8, L9, atmve, atmvebar, 
  atmv\[Mu], atmv\[Mu]bar, DSNve, DSNvebar, DSNvx}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-1, 10^3}, {10^-4, 10^12}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.8, Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 16], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Nu]\)]\)(MeV)", 
   "Differential flux (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(MeV\), \
\(-1\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \
\(-1\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\))"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Darker[Black], Thick], Directive[Red, Thick],
    Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick], Directive[Darker[Green], Thick], 
   Directive[Darker[Magenta], Thick], 
   Directive[Darker[Orange], Thick], 
   Directive[Darker[Black], Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Darker[Green], Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Darker[Magenta], Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Darker[Orange], Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Darker[Black], Thick, DotDashed], 
   Directive[Red, Thick, DotDashed], 
   Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick, DotDashed], 
   Directive[Darker[Green], Thick, DotDashed]}, FrameTicks -> ticks1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Darker[Black], Thick], 
     Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick], 
     Directive[Darker[Green], Thick], 
     Directive[Darker[Magenta], Thick], 
     Directive[Darker[Orange], Thick], 
     Directive[Darker[Black], Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Darker[Green], Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Darker[Magenta], Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Darker[Orange], Thick, Dashed], 
     Directive[Darker[Black], Thick, DotDashed], 
     Directive[Red, Thick, DotDashed], 
     Directive[Lighter[Blue], Thick, DotDashed], 
     Directive[Darker[Green], Thick, DotDashed]}, {"pp", "hep", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(13\)]\)N", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(15\)]\)O", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(17\)]\)F", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(8\)]\)B", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \
\(7\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Be\), \(861.3\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \
\(7\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Be\), \(384.3\)]\)", "pep", 
     "atm: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(e\)]\)", 
     "atm:" Subscript[OverBar[\[Nu]], e], 
     "atm: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(\[Mu]\)]\)", 
     "atm:" Subscript[OverBar[\[Nu]], \[Mu]], 
     "DSN: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(e\)]\)", 
     "DSN:" Subscript[OverBar[\[Nu]], e], 
     "DSN: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(x\)]\)"}, 
    LegendMargins -> {{0.001, 0.001}, {0.0000001, 0.0000001}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {25}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 11]], Below]]
```

Now I get this following output, Where the Legend is in left alignment:-[image]

But I want the Legend to be in justify (perfect) alignment in the row. So, can anyone help me how I can do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[15];
labels = Array["label" <> ToString @ # &, 15];

legend = LineLegend[colors, labels, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]
```

[image]

**1.** You can wrap each label with [`Pane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) and specify the same `ImageSize`:

```
is = Map[Max]@Transpose[Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] & /@ labels]
```

> ```
> {49, 15}
> ```

```
pane = Pane[#, ImageSize -> is] & ;

LineLegend[colors, pane  /@ labels, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, post-process `legend` to wrap each label with `pane`:

```
MapAt[Map[pane], legend, {2}]
```

[image]

**2.** You can use a custom function as the setting for [`LegendLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout.html):

```
legendlayout = Grid[Row[#, Spacer[2]] & /@ # & /@ Partition[#, 8, 8, 1, {}], 
    Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {1, .5}] &;

LineLegend[colors, labels, LegendLayout -> legendlayout]
```

[image]